# git log command prints nothing in chroot

Tags: git, debian, chroot, jail

I made chroot jail using script make_chroot_jail.sh, then added git by copying /usr/bin/git*, all libraries that these binaries need and /usr/share/git-core
now i can init, clone commit, push and so on in jail, but when i type git log it prints nothing(
could somebody help me or say where to look for?

Comment: Have you tried running it with strace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing a chroot, try running the commands with `strace -f` and look for abnormally failing system calls, missing files etc. `strace -f <command> 2>&1 |grep ...` is your friend.

Needless to say, constructing a chroot with a complex software is not for the faintest of hearts...

Comment: Thank you very match:)
strace command is great!
Resolution: git log runs pager (/usr/bin/pager -> /bin/less) that i'd forgotten to into chroot.